# ReactJS: How to custom styles using `react-dates`

Tags: reactjs, react-dates

I wanna custom styles using [react-dates](https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates) lib for below
[image]

Do you have suggestions for me? Many thanks

Comment: The link you gave literally has a whole section on how to override the styles. https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates#overriding-styles

Comment: In the readme, there is a section talking about theming: https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates#theming. You may customize the look and feel by creating your own theme.

Comment: I just resolved this, thanks everyone :)